# JenkinsCI : zipalign failed on APK : exit code 1

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, zipalign

I am using Jenkins for building my android project. We use [Android Signing Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/android-signing/) to sign apks. Recently on one branch it is failing with the following error log:

```
[SignApksBuilder] /var/lib/jenkins/android-sdk/build-tools/29.0.2/zipalign -f -p 4 /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Android/app/build/outputs/apk/production/release/app_productionRelease_0.11.1_HEAD_3048d80.apk /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Android/SignApksBuilder-out/zipalign/aligned-app_productionRelease_0.11.1_HEAD_3048d80-1628945884194489230.apk
[Android] $ /var/lib/jenkins/android-sdk/build-tools/29.0.2/zipalign -f -p 4 /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Android/app/build/outputs/apk/production/release/app_productionRelease_0.11.1_HEAD_3048d80.apk /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Android/SignApksBuilder-out/zipalign/aligned-app_productionRelease_0.11.1_HEAD_3048d80-1628945884194489230.apk
FATAL: [SignApksBuilder] zipalign failed: exit code 1
ERROR: zipalign failed on APK /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Android/app/build/outputs/apk/production/release/app_productionRelease_0.11.1_HEAD_3048d80.apk: exit code 1
```

This is a release build and the only meaningful changes on this branch is

- update android gradle plugin from `4.0.2` to `4.1.0`
- update gradle from `6.1.1` to `6.5`

Can anyone shed some light on what is going wrong?

PS: I tried to post issue to [Jenkins Jira](https://issues.jenkins.io/issues/?jql=project%3DJENKINS%20AND%20component%3Dandroid-signing-plugin) as the plugin readme says but seems like the Log in feature is broken :/

Thanks!

Comment: TBF, i don't think AGP version is the real issue. For this specific project the solution was to downgrade to `4.0.2`, however we have another project where it is failing for AGP `4.0.2` and gradle `6.1.1`

Answer (score 0):

after fighting with this weird issue I downgrade from `4.1.0` to `4.0.2`. This solve the issue looks like **zipalign** plugin in Jenkins hasn't been updated in **3 years**, maybe this will be solve with next update of the **zipAlignPlugin** in **Jenkins**.

Comment: Does the android signing plugin use zipAlignPlugin internally?

Comment: I also have this problem with gradle plugin 4.1.1 and gradle version 6.7.1. seems like there is a bug in the plugin?

Comment: Yes It does use zip align internally

Comment: Used external zipalign from build tools 29.0.2 w/ Jenkins, same issue

Comment: Zeems resolved in zipalign recently, not sure how to use it
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/162117652#comment21

Comment: TBF, i don't think AGP version is the real issue. For this specific project the solution was to downgrade to `4.0.2`, however we have another project where it is failing for AGP `4.0.2` and gradle `6.1.1`

Comment: I have sole this issue by enabling zipAlign on Gradle in the release buildType, and skipZip in Jenkins, after all I need to sign it and gradle can handle the rest :)

Comment: Does this mean that jarsigner is no longer a supported means of signing apks?

Comment: Im not sure, I just moved to use the zipAlign in Gradle, seems to work just fine :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly running zipalign is not necessary atleast on the latest AGP as mentioned on this [issue thread](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/162117652)
It can be used to verify if the output release apk is aligned properly.

```
zipalign -c -v 4 signed.apk
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to use zipalign on gradle project options, works well, but I haven't tried anymore the plugin In Jenkins that contains the zipalign for signing apks.